# Filter payment method based on state

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, filter

Would it be possible somehow to filter the payment methods on default Magento one page checkout based on the state customer chooses for shipping address? Tried to look for an extension, but could not find one that would work without customer having to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amasty had an extension that did just what we needed:
https://amasty.com/payment-restrictions.html